# Matplotlib turn off axis and set background color for subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot two subplots consisting of only text. I want to remove the axis of both subplots and add a background color, using the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2)

ax[0].text(0.5,0.2,'some text')
ax[0].set_facecolor('grey')

ax[1].text(0.5,0.2,'more text')
ax[1].axis('off')
ax[1].set_facecolor('grey')

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

The problem is that `ax[1].axis('off')` removes both the axis and the background color. Is there a way I can remove the axis and keep the background color?